# Pythonanywhere [Flask] - Creating a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pythonanywhere

I would like to create a database that stores all passwords. I followed this tutorial and it worked when I made exactly the same as they did, but now I want to make my own database. I already made a database actually and it shows the right tables and "describe (tablename)" also works, but when I do select * from (tablename);, it returns Empty set (0.00 sec). That means that nothing is stored but I did post some password on my website.

**This is the flask_app.py code:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/{databasename}".format(
    username="*******", //I filled these in
    password="*******",
    hostname="*******.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com",
    databasename="******$wachtwoorden",
)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Wachtwoord(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "wachtwoorden"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(80))

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])

def main():

    if request.method == "GET":
        print("in request.method = get")
        return render_template("main_page.html")

    if (request.form["Knop1"] == "1912"):
        print ('Het wachtwoord is geraden:', request.form["Knop1"])
        return redirect("http://tegelizr.nl/tegeltjes/dat-klopt-als-een-bus.png")

    else:
        print ('Iemand heeft een het wachtwoord geraden:', request.form["Knop1"])
        return render_template("main_page.html")

    wachtwoord = Wachtwoord(content=request.form["Knop1"])
    db.session.add(wachtwoord)
    db.session.commit()
```

**This is in my main_page.html**

```
<form method="POST">
     <p>
        <center>
           <br><br><br><h2>Wat is het wachtwoord?</h2><input type="text" name="Knop1" value = "" />
           <br><br><input type="image" src="http://www.kryshiggins.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/KrystalsNewMergedThemeOMG/Krys_Images/Next_Arrow.png" alt="Submit" width="30" height="30"><br><br><br>
        </center>
    </form>
```

So how do I store the passwords the right way?
Sorry, but wachtwoord means password. Oh and it might be a bit confusing, because you just have to give the right password, which is 1912, then why do I want to store the attempted passwords? Well, it's just a test for me and if this works I know how to do it in the future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a return to render your template before it is able to call your database insert. Try this:

```
def main():

    if request.method == "GET":
        print("in request.method = get")
        return render_template("main_page.html")

    if (request.form["Knop1"] == "1912"):
        print ('Het wachtwoord is geraden:', request.form["Knop1"])
        wachtwoord = Wachtwoord(content=request.form["Knop1"])
        db.session.add(wachtwoord)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect("http://tegelizr.nl/tegeltjes/dat-klopt-als-een-bus.png")

    else:
        print ('Iemand heeft een het wachtwoord geraden:', request.form["Knop1"])
        return render_template("main_page.html")
```

Comment: Little question, what if I wanted to add another text input, which contains someone's name. This is request.form["Knop2"]. How would I make it so that is get's stored into my database like "request.form["Knop2"]: request.form["Knop1"]", in other words "Name: Password"

Comment: @Jip1912 I would suggest reading up on this link: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html. It will give you all the basics you need to know on using SQLAlchemy. You can also look at this site, which is a bit more comprehensive: http://www.rmunn.com/sqlalchemy-tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: I will read it, but at the moment I really don't have the time. Why does      wachtwoord = Wachtwoord(content=request.form["Knop2"]:, request.form["Knop1"]) not work? How should I do it? I will read it tommorow.

Comment: Try: Wachtwoord(content=request.form.get("Knop2"), other_column=request.form.get("Knop1")). This is just pseudo code without seeing your actual database definition with your new column. The 2nd link I gave you will give you the better way to do this.

Comment: I did it like this: https://pastebin.com/169Ut2QY, but as you can see in the pastebin it returns poging-null and then null-name. How can I make it poging-name? I do commit after adding them right?